# printf formatting equivalent in cpp's cout

Tags: c++, c, io, formatting, iomanip

I am currently a student of Computer Science, and today I received an extra-ordinary assignment, which should be written under C++. I was learning full C until today. This is more like a blind assignment.

In C, I usually use this:

```
printf("\n\n\t%-30s %-7d liters\n\t%-30s %-7d liters\n\t%-30s %-7d km",
       "Current gasoline in reserve:",
       db.currentGas,
       "Total gasoline used:",
       db.usedGas,
       "Total travel distance:",
       db.usedGas);
```

Since the assignment's condition is that it should be written in C++, this is what I've tried:

```
cout << setw(30) << "\n\n\tCurrent gasoline in reserve: "
     << setw(7) << db.currentGas << "litres"
     << setw(30) << "\n\tTotal gasoline used: "
     << setw(7) << db.usedGas << "litres"
     << setw(30) << "\n\tTotal travel distance: "
     << setw(7) << db.travelDistance << "km";
```

But it looks like there is a differences between C's `%-30s` and C++'s `setw(30)`?

Comment: I will never understand people giving negative votes to a perfectly valid question, including code of what has been tried and being specific about what it is asked. Trolls maybe?

Comment: Actually, using printf is absolutely legal in C++, too... You'd prefer to `#include <cstdio>` over `#include <stdio.h>` then, though. I personally use printf (and sometimes (s)scanf) function quite often, as it can be more handy than the C++ streams. On the other hand, the latter ones come in quite handy if complex classes are involved or typedefs you do not expect to be the same on all platforms involved (think of `uint32_t` for instance...). So if assignment requires C++ only, you could leave the calls to printf as are - if requirement is explicitly to use streams, then you need to change...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Still good practice to avoid the printf() / scanf() family of functions, for the various potentially fatal errors they allow (due to being variadic functions, i.e. no type checking). Plus, I'd stay well clear of any scanf() even in C -- its only *marginally* easier to get a scanf() call right than it was with gets()...

Comment: @DevSolar Truth, scanf I normally don't use - prefer to read a whole line at once (**f**gets) and use **s**scanf afterwards - *if* I do... Don't get me wrong, I appreciate C++ streams very much. But sometimes, good old printf family comes in just more handy than the streams, compare `fprintf(stderr, "[...] failed with error %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));` vs. `std::cerr << "[...] failed with error " << errno << " (" << strerror(errno) << ')' << std::endl;`. And if there is code already working correctly, I would stay with it, following the maxim of never touching a running system..

Comment: @Aconcagua: Agreed, if it's there **and** tested, don't touch it. But I go to some lengths avoiding such constructs in *new* code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed there is a difference, like this:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall main.cpp
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 


    Current gasoline in reserve:       6litres       
    Total gasoline used:       5litres     
    Total travel distance:       4kmGeorgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -W
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 


    Current gasoline in reserve:   6       liters
    Total gasoline used:           5       liters
    Total travel distance:         4       kmGeorgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$
```

But the question is *where* is the difference?

`setw(30)` is equivalent to `%30s`, **but**, you have used `-30s`, which left-aligns the output! In order to get a similar behavior, use [std::left](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/left/), like this:

```
cout << "\n\n" << left << setw(30) << "\tCurrent gasoline in reserve: " << left << setw(7) << 6 << "litres\n" << left << setw(30) << "\tTotal gasoline used: " << left << setw(7) << 5 << "litres\n" << left << setw(30) << "\tTotal travel distance: " << left << setw(7) << 4 << "km";
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I'm sorry if the question was a bit dumb, I'm totally new to C++ :)

Comment: Some years back I was at the same level as you, when I started learning C++ in uni, so no dumb question, I upvoted it @TenzoNakami! =) You are welcome.

Comment: It should be `cout << "\n\n\t" << setw(30) << left << "Current gasoline..."` as you don't want to count the newlines/tabs.

Comment: Indeed @KlitosKyriacou, I was just about to modify my answer, but thank you! :)

Comment: Thank you all for supporting me! I've been using StackOverflow since my first day in the university, but the community always is amazing :) Thank you for supporting people who's on the learning curve like me!

Answer (score 3):

Minus in `printf` does left alignment.

To do that in C++ you need [`std::left`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left)

Comment: According to gsamaras's answer, this is indeed a true answer. But a little bit more explanation is always appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

In C++20 you will be able to use `std::format` for this which is very easy to translate from `printf`:

```cpp
std::cout << std::format(
       "\n\n\t{:30} {:<7} liters\n\t{:30} {:<7} liters\n\t{:30} {:<7} km",
       "Current gasoline in reserve:",
       db.currentGas,
       "Total gasoline used:",
       db.usedGas,
       "Total travel distance:",
       db.usedGas);
```

In the meantime you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on. {fmt} also provides the `print` function that makes this even easier and more efficient ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/49r5MW)):

```
fmt::print(
       "\n\n\t{:30} {:<7} liters\n\t{:30} {:<7} liters\n\t{:30} {:<7} km",
       "Current gasoline in reserve:",
       db.currentGas,
       "Total gasoline used:",
       db.usedGas,
       "Total travel distance:",
       db.usedGas);
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.